# Jquery selected tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna get selected id from my tabs. I tried anything but but I am very weak in javascript. This my tabs.

```
<li><a href="#tab" class="days" id="day_1">Pondelok</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab" class="days" id="day_2">Utorok</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab" class="days" id="day_3">Streda</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab" class="days" id="day_4">Štvrtok</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab" class="days" id="day_5">Piatok</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab" class="days" id="day_6">Sobota</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab" class="days" id="day_7">Nedeľa</a></li>
```

This is my attempt, which return undefined.

```
<script>
     var selected_tab = $(".ui-state-active").attr("id"); 
     document.write(selected_tab);
</script>
```

Comment: did you add your code between $(doument).ready(); instead of directly putting it in a script tag, to make sure that the DOM is loaded when you run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will alert id of tab on which you have clicked

```
$('.days').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

if you want to write it on document use this

```
$('.days').click(function(){
  document.write($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Live Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/zgDYZ/

Comment: Thank you it works fine but if I want it send to php script how can I continue?

Comment: sorry no idea about phpscript bro.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var selecId = "";
$('.days').click(function(){
  selecId = $(this).attr('id');
});
</script>
```

Use `selecId` where ever you want..

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to to get attribute from class `.ui-state-active` which doesn't exist as per your markup. So your code wont work:

Try the below and this will work:

```
$(function() {
            $("ul li").each(function() {
            var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("id"); 
            alert(selected_tab);

            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.days').click(function () {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

another best way with validations

$('a.days').click(function(){

alert($(this).attr('id'));
});